# How to make a string invisible?

Tags: php, variables, string

I have a snippet below that uses $name to display a person's name.  If the name isn't there it says No name added.  How can i make it so that instead of saying that variable will display nothing at all?

```
     $name = "Name - $variablefromdatabase";

     // If $name is empty
     if (empty($name)) {

     $name = "No Name added";
     }
```

Comment: Remove `if (empty($name)) {...}`...?

Comment: Your original code does not do what you describe. Consider fixing that part first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$name = (strlen($varFromDb) > 0) ? "Name - " . $varFromDb : "";
```

If I understood the question correctly, if the user has no name set, nothing should be displayed, else it's see to `Name - {their name}`

Comment: OK that did it.  But how do i add a <label></label> to the $varfromDB?

Comment: You would just do `$name = (strlen($varFromDb) > 0) ? "Name - <label for='something'>" . $varFromDb . "</labe>": "";`

Comment: Thanks that worked.  one last thing is for another field i need to do something like $varfromdb1/$varfromdb2.  I was able to do it but it wouldn't work if a value is not there then it would still display the Name tag.

Comment: So if `$varfromdb1` divided by `$varfromdb2`? What do you want to do with that?

Comment: Never mind.  I found an alternative solution for storing that particular information that works well with your snippet. Thanks Marcus.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your current code does not do what you say it does. Here is why:

You initialize **$name** as "Name - $variablefromdatabase". Thus even it **$variablefromdatabase** is empty you will still end up with a string which is "Name - ". This is not seen as empty and thus the code will never go into the if-statement. Below is a more correct version

```
// If $name is empty
if (empty($variablefromdatabase)) {
    $name = "Name - $variablefromdatabase";
} else {
    $name = "No Name added"; // or $name = "Name - No Name added"
}
```

On to the next part of your question; How can you display nothing when no value is returned from the database. Try the code below:

```
$variablefromdatabase = trim( $variablefromdatabase ); // just make sure there is no white space

if (! empty( $variablefromdatabase ) ) { // check if an empty value is returned from the database
    $name = "Name - $variablefromdatabase"; // not empty, so set the name variable
} else {
    $name = ""; // set the name variable to an empty string
}
```

Comment: Hey.  What if there is a white space?

Comment: You'll see in the second code example I trim the value received from the database. The [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will remove any white space before and after the string, but will remove all white space if the string only consists of white space.